# Get stackoverflow error when mapping OneToOne relation with a composite primary key

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to write a OneToOne relation with three tables: Owner, Property and OwnerProperty
The OwnerProperty has a composite primary key formed by 2 foreign keys of the property and owner
Diagram:
[image]

Owner class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Owner")
public class Owner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="ownerPropertyKey.owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "ownerPropertyKey.owner", allowSetters = true)
    private OwnerProperty ownerProperty;
```

Property class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Property")
public class Property {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="ownerPropertyKey.property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "ownerPropertyKey.property", allowSetters = true)
    private OwnerProperty ownerProperty;
```

OwnerProperty Class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "OwnerProperty")
public class OwnerProperty {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OwnerPropertyKey ownerPropertyKey;

    public OwnerProperty(OwnerPropertyKey ownerPropertyKey){
        this.ownerPropertyKey = ownerPropertyKey;
    }

    public OwnerProperty(){

    }
}
```

OwnerPropertyKey class:

```
@Data
@Setter
@Getter
@Embeddable
public class OwnerPropertyKey implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "ownerProperty", allowSetters=true)
    private Owner owner;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "ownerProperty", allowSetters=true)
    private Property property;

    public OwnerPropertyKey(Owner owner, Property property){
        this.owner = owner;
        this.property = property;
    }

    public OwnerPropertyKey(){

    }
}
```

And the error I get when I try to save an ownerProperty:
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
    at com.mikason.PropView.controller.OwnerPropertyControllerTest.testAddOwnerProperty(OwnerPropertyControllerTest.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:155)
...
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mikason</groupId>
    <artifactId>PropView</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PropView</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>test</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I can't find where the problem is, could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: post your pom.xml

Comment: @Maheshkumar Hi, I have added my pom.xml, please have a look, thanks you.

Comment: may i know the reason for join table in one to one mapping? If still required, may i know the reason for composite PK in join table?

Comment: Ehhh, I also think this OneToOne composite table is strange, but my supervisor designed this database structure, I'm just implement it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I checked with my supervisor, he admitted he draw the picture wrong...thank you for answerirng my question.